# Issue with Insert Method on a B+Tree

Tags: python-3.x, database, b-tree

I have been trying to learn more about databases in depth and attempting to implement a B+Tree in Python. I have a problem with inserting a key value pair into the tree, and I can't identify the source of the issue.

When I run the series of commands specified in the Python file, the output I get resembles the following:

```
Root
    Internal Node: 
        (5, Range: 5, 6)
    Left Child:
        Internal Node: 
            (3, Range: 3, 4)
        Root
            Internal Node: 
                (3, Range: 3, 4)
            Left Child:
                Leaf Node: 
                    (1, 1)
                    (2, 2)
            Right Child:
                Leaf Node: 
                    (3, 3)
                    (4, 4)
    Right Child:
        Internal Node: 
            (5, Range: 5, 5)
            (6, Range: 6, 8)
        Root
            Internal Node: 
                (5, Range: 5, 5)
                (6, Range: 6, 8)
            Left Child:
                Leaf Node: 
                    (5, 5)
            Right Child:
                Leaf Node: 
                    (5, 5)
            Right Child:
                Leaf Node: 
                    (6, 6)
                    (8, 8)
```

The last root has a left child which is the `(key, value)` pair of `(5, 5)` which is wrong that should be located as the right child of that cell. In fact the right child is correct but for some reason this additional left child shows up.

I am using the algorithm outlined in Database Internals. The range of the separator keys is left inclusive and not right inclusive, so I have a left child pointer in each tree node.

[image]

```
from bisect import bisect_left
from enum import Enum
import json

class NodeType(Enum):
    LEAF = 0
    INTERNAL = 1

class LeafNodeCell:
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"({self.key}, {self.value})"

    def print(self, indent):
        print ('\t'*indent + f"({self.key}, {self.value})")

class InternalNodeCell:
    def __init__(self, key, right_child_pointer):
        self.key = key
        self.right_child_pointer = right_child_pointer

    def print(self, indent):
        print ('\t' *indent + f"({self.key}, Range: {self.right_child_pointer.cells[0].key}, {self.right_child_pointer.cells[-1].key})")

class BTreeNode:
    def __init__(self, type: NodeType):
        self.type = type or NodeType.LEAF
        self.num_of_cells = 0
        self.cells = []
        self.parent = None
        self.left_child_pointer = None #   This is only used for internal nodes
        self.right_sibling_pointer = None #   This is only used for leaf nodes

    def print(self, indent):
        if self.type is NodeType.LEAF:
            print('\t' * indent + "Leaf Node: ")
            for cell in self.cells:
                cell.print(indent+1)
        elif self.type is NodeType.INTERNAL:
            print('\t' * indent + "Internal Node: ")
            for cell in self.cells:
                cell.print(indent+1)

class BTree:
    def __init__(self, order):
        self.root = BTreeNode(NodeType.LEAF)
        self.order = order

    def print(self, root, indent=0):
        if root is None:
            return
        print('\t' * indent + 'Root')
        root.print(indent+1)
        if root.type is NodeType.INTERNAL and root.left_child_pointer is not None:
            print ('\t' * (indent + 1) + "Left Child:")
            root.left_child_pointer.print(indent+2)
            if root.left_child_pointer.type is NodeType.INTERNAL:
                self.print(root.left_child_pointer, indent+2)
        for cell in root.cells:
            if isinstance(cell, InternalNodeCell):
                print('\t' * (indent + 1) + "Right Child:")
                cell.right_child_pointer.print(indent+2)
                if cell.right_child_pointer.type is NodeType.INTERNAL:
                    self.print(cell.right_child_pointer, indent+2)

    def search(self, key):
        node, index = self._search(key)
        if index < len(node.cells) and node.cells[index].key == key:
            return True
        return False
    
    def get(self, key):
        node, index = self._search(key)
        if index < len(node.cells) and node.cells[index].key == key:
            return node.cells[index].value
        return None
    
    def insert(self, key, value):
        node, index = self._search(key)

        #   If the key already exists in the database
        if index < len(node.cells) and node.cells[index].key == key:
            node.cells[index].value = value
            return True
        
        #   If the key does not currently exist in the database
        self._insert(node, key, value)

    def _insert(self, node, key, value):
        #   Check if the node is full
        insertion_index = bisect_left(node.cells, key, key=lambda x: x.key)
        if node.type is NodeType.LEAF and node.num_of_cells < self.order - 1:
            #   This node will not overflow, add the key value pair
            node.cells.insert(insertion_index, LeafNodeCell(key, value))
            node.num_of_cells += 1
            return node

        if node.type is NodeType.INTERNAL and node.num_of_cells < self.order - 1:
            node.cells.insert(insertion_index, InternalNodeCell(key, value))
            node.num_of_cells += 1
            return node
        
        #   This node will overflow
        
        #   If this node is the root node
        if node.parent is None:
            #   Create a new root node
            new_root = BTreeNode(NodeType.INTERNAL)
            node.parent = new_root
            self.root = new_root

        #   Create a new sibling node first and move half the elements from the current node to the sibling node
        temp_node_cells = node.cells[:]
        sibling_node = BTreeNode(node.type)
        middle_index = node.num_of_cells // 2
        node.cells = node.cells[:middle_index]
        sibling_node.cells = temp_node_cells[middle_index:]
        node.num_of_cells = len(node.cells)
        sibling_node.num_of_cells = len(sibling_node.cells)

        if node.type is NodeType.LEAF:
            #   Place the key into the correct node
            if insertion_index <= middle_index:
                node.cells.insert(insertion_index, LeafNodeCell(key, value))
                node.num_of_cells += 1
            else:
                sibling_node.cells.insert(insertion_index - middle_index, LeafNodeCell(key, value))
                sibling_node.num_of_cells += 1

            key_to_promote = sibling_node.cells[0].key
            parent_node = self._insert(node.parent, key_to_promote, sibling_node)
            node.parent = parent_node
            sibling_node.parent = parent_node
            parent_node.left_child_pointer = node

        if node.type is NodeType.INTERNAL:
            #   Place the key into the correct node
            if insertion_index <= middle_index:
                node.cells.insert(insertion_index, InternalNodeCell(key, value))
                node.num_of_cells += 1
            else:
                sibling_node.cells.insert(insertion_index - middle_index, InternalNodeCell(key, value))
                sibling_node.num_of_cells += 1

            key_to_promote = sibling_node.cells[0].key
            parent_node = self._insert(node.parent, key_to_promote, sibling_node)
            node.parent = parent_node
            sibling_node.parent = parent_node
            parent_node.left_child_pointer = node
            
            if insertion_index <= middle_index:
                return node
            return sibling_node

    def _search(self, key):
        node = self.root
        while node.type is not NodeType.LEAF:
            index = bisect_left(node.cells, key, key=lambda x: x.key)
            if index == 0:
                node = node.left_child_pointer
            else:
                node = node.cells[index - 1].right_child_pointer
        index = bisect_left(node.cells, key, key=lambda x: x.key)
        return node, index

if __name__ == "__main__":
    btree = BTree(3)
    btree.insert(3, 3)
    btree.insert(5, 5)
    btree.insert(1, 1)
    btree.insert(2, 2)
    btree.insert(4, 4)
    btree.insert(6, 6)
    btree.insert(8, 8)
    btree.print(btree.root)
```

Comment: *"I think I might have some small bugs"*: why do you think that? Was there some test that failed? Have you subjected your code to massive testing?

Comment: @trincot - Yeah, the specific test case I have in my code adds an additional left child pointer to the rightmost node of the b+-tree. You can see that when `btree.print(btree.root)` is run.

Comment: Can you focus your question on that problem?

Comment: OK, I edited it more, because asking for a code review is off topic here.

Comment: @trincot Out of curiosity, what is the right site on the SE platform to ask for code reviews?

Comment: That would be [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but they have their own scope of what is on topic. Make sure to read those points.